# AngularJS how to write functions in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

For me AngularJS directives looks like wrapped functionality, like some web component. I am trying to wrap progress bar from Bootstrap i.e.:

[image: Bootstrap progress bar]

I made basic directive thats fine, but I would like to add some API to that component. Some functions which I can use in *controller* that could control component behaviour. E.g. start, stop, reset, gotopercent etc. I made that functions at controller but I think it is not best practice since that functions should belong to directive, not a controller so I can easily reuse it in other pages.

**Question:**

How to create functions in AngularJS directive which allows me to control component behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> I made that functions at controller but I think it is not best practice since that functions should belong to directive, not a controller so I can easily reuse it in other pages.

Well, no. Functions do belong into controllers - but directives can have their own controller where you define your "directive API" independent from you *ApplicationController* or *PageController*.

Take a look at the [angular-ui/bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) repo, where there's already a directive for the [bootstrap progressbar](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/progressbar).